# Android - Jsoup select particular links

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to parse a few links in my Android app using Jsoup. I'm able to parse it properly but what I want to achieve is that I only want the links from the first block i.e **Degree College**

Is there any way I can only list the links from specific block?

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

        Document doc;
        String desc;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

            links = doc.select("p a[href$=.pdf]");

            linkList.clear();            

            for (Element pdfLink : links) {

                desc = pdfLink.text();
                linkList.add(desc);
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Here's the source of HTML

```
<p align="center"><b><font color="Maroon">Degree College</font></b></p>
  <font size=1>(6)</font>      <div class="ScrollStyle">
           <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/Aug-2015/dg college identity distibution 2015-16.pdf">IMPORTANT NOTICE FOR DEGREE COLLEGE STUDENTS FOR IDENTITY CARDS 2015-16</a></p>
            <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/Aug-2015/dr..caste procudure 2015 -26 notice.pdf">FREESHIP/SCHOLARSHIP PROCEDURE 2015-2016</a></p>
            <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/Aug-2015/reg & sfc prg class test notice 2015-16.pdf">Documents required to be eligible for Class Test August-2015</a></p>
            <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/Aug-2015/all repeater students oct-2015.pdf">TYBSC/TYBCOM REPEATER EXAM FORMS OCT-2015</a></p>
            <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/July-2015/FYRollCallTimeTable.html">FY Roll Call & TimeTable</a></p>
            <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/July-2015/degree college class test august -2015.pdf">DEGREE COLLEGE CLASS TEST SEM-I/III/V AUGUST-2015</a></p>
       </div>   


<b><center><p><font color="Maroon">Junior College</font></p></center></b>
<font size=1>(8)</font>    <div class="ScrollStyle">
       <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/Aug-2015/xi caste verification marksheets.pdf">FYJC/SYJC SCIENCE STUDENTS VERIFICATION OF CASTE CERTIFICATE 2015-16</a></p>
        <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/Aug-2015/jr.caste procedure notice 2015-16.pdf">FREESHIP/SCHOLARSHIP PROCEDURE 2015-2016</a></p>
        <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/Aug-2015/xii examination form notice fe-2016.pdf">NOTICE FOR HSC EXAMINATION FORM DISTRIBUTION FEBRUARY-2016</a></p>
        <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/Aug-2015/xi first unit test examination sep-2015.pdf">FYJC FIRST UNIT TEST & EXAMINATION IN H & PE SEPTEMBER -2015</a></p>
        <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/Aug-2015/FYJC IDENTITY CARD NOTICE 2015-16.pdf">FYJC -IDENTITY CARDS & LIBRARY CARDS DISTRIBUTION NOTICE 2015-2016</a></p>
        <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/July-2015/xii  science com  mathematics practicals 2015-16.pdf">SYJC SCIENCE/COMMERCE Compulsory Attendance in Mathematics Practical 2015-2016</a></p>
        <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/July-2015/JuniorRollCall.html">Junior College Roll Call And Time Table Yr 2015-16</a></p>
        <p align="Left"><img src="image/new.gif" /><a href="Notice2015-16/June-2015/HSC Result Notice.pdf">HSC RESULTS, FEBRUARY / MARCH 2015</a></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Element firstBockDiv = doc.select("div.ScrollStyle").first();
links = firstBockDiv.select("p a[href$=.pdf]");
```

If you need the header, i.e. the name of the college it is a bit tricky, since the element containing the name is a sibling to the bockDiv. You can do this for example:

```
String name = firstBockDiv
                .previousElementSibling()
                .previousElementSibling()
                .text();
```

Comment: Both the codes you mentioned worked just fine. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the requested hrefs are NOT children of the requested block ("Degree College"), you need to find the element that contains both the requested hrefs, and the requested block.

Let's assume it is the *document* itself.

Then, you can go over its immediate children:

```
Elements children = document.children();
```

And search every child element if it contains the requested block.
Once you found it, the next child which is of type *div*, is the container that contains the requested hrefs (assuming the structure you wrote holds).

The JSoup API has much more than the css selector, you can check it [here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/).